# Which SCTP event should I expect if remote side changes IP?

Tags: sctp

We have code that should handle that the remote side of an SCTP connection changes its IP address, but we're unsure of what that would look like on a protocol level. What, if any, event would that produce?

Comment: HVe you read the RFC for SCTP already? If not, you should since it likely answers all of your questions.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4960

Comment: I have not read every millimeter of it, no. But I couldn't identify anything obviously mapping to something unexpected like that.

Comment: Read the part where SCTP actually allows multiple addressing on a connection.